# Max function with CASE

Tags: sql

use of MAX function with case statement .What role MAX has to play.PLease give with a example

Comment: This sounds rather like a test question. When seeking assistance you should demonstrate what you have done to try and resolve the problem yourself, your current SQL and how it is expected to work versus the result you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Max() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp)

Definiton and Usage :

> The MAX() function returns the largest value of the selected column.

Simple Case :

```
SELECT 
MAX(Case when Price not null then Price else 0 end) AS LargestPrice
FROM Products;
```

When use in `Case` like example above you are going to Max or return the largest value from price when column `Price` not null

[Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_max)

Try my query in link demo